# How to show name of attribute instead of "item" in XML output

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl

I'm writing a WSDL file and it's working. However, the output doesn't look exactly what I like to see. So, I have defined output message like this:

```
<message name="serviceResponse">
  <part name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
  <part name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
  <part name="results" element="tns:myProperty"/>
</message>
```

And in <types> tag, I have:

```
<xsd:element name="myProperty">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
      <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:date"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

In response, I got:

```
<SOAP-ENV:serviceResponse>
  <code xsi:type="xsd:string">001</code>
  <description xsi:type="xsd:string">Successful</description>
  <results SOAP-ENC:arrayType="SOAP-ENC:Array[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
    <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[7]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">John</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">Director</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:int">21</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">2012-10-16</item>
    </item>
    <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[7]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">Smith</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">Programmer</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:int">88</item>
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">2012-10-18</item>
    </item>
  </results>
</SOAP-ENV:serviceResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I would expected to get something like following within "results" tag, rather than a bunch of "item"s:

```
<myProperty SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[7]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
  <name xsi:type="xsd:string">John</name>
  <description xsi:type="xsd:string">Director</description>
  <id xsi:type="xsd:int">21</id>
  <date xsi:type="xsd:string">2012-10-16</date>
</myProperty>
<myProperty SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[7]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
  <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Smith</name>
  <description xsi:type="xsd:string">Programmer</description>
  <id xsi:type="xsd:int">88</id>
  <date xsi:type="xsd:string">2012-10-18</date>
</myProperty>
```

Can anyone please shed a light? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by viewing another post from: [WSDL list of complexType HOWTO- define, return from a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229941/wsdl-list-of-complextype-howto-define-return-from-a-service)

No DTD definition required. Thanks to [so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726532/so) anyway.

What I have done is slightly different. Instead of using an element named "myProperty", I defined a complexType directly with the name "myProperty". It just worked.

```
<xsd:complexType name="myProperty">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:date"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="serviceResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="myResult" nillable="true" type="tns:myProperty"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The output is exactly what I expected:

```
<myProperty xsi:type="ns1:myProperty">
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Smith</name>
    <description xsi:type="xsd:string">Programmer</description>
    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">88</id>
    <date xsi:type="xsd:date">2012-10-18</date>
</myProperty>
```

Comment: Can someone explain why? I've literally had the opposite problem and I've been trying to resolve it for 3 days. I thought I'd wrap my complexType with "element" out of desperation, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Define DTD for your myProperty tag correctly.

Somthing like:

```
<!ELEMENT myProperty (name,description,id,date)>
<!ELEMENT name(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT id(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date(#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But where do I define them? In which section? Sorry, I'm a newbie to web services

Comment: You must have defined "Result" tag. Below that definition you can put this code. Inside Doctype declaration. U can find more information at "http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_intro.asp"